# Check types of an array in typescript

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree

Typescript seems to work very well with AST apparently. If I check `x.type == "Abc"`, then the next line, typescript knows `x` is of type `Abc`. Note that I use it to typecheck JS files with type annotations in JSDOC format. But I guess the same holds for pure typescript files

However, I have issues testing for an array of elements.

This first example works, because I loop over every element, and only push it when the type is checked. So typescript correctly deduces the type `Property[]` as the return type of the function

```
/**
 * @param {ObjectExpression} objectAst
 */
function getPropertiesList(objectAst) {
    let propertiesList = []
    for (let p of objectAst.value.properties) {
        if (p.type == "Property")
            propertiesList.push(p)
        else
            throw new Error("Properties field has elements that aren't of type `Property`")
    }
    return propertiesList
}
```

This example however, which is functionally the same (but is cleaner in my eyes and doesn't create a new array) doesn't work. The inferred type is `(SpreadElement|Property|ObjectMethod|ObjectProperty|SpreadProperty)[]`. So it doesn't take the check into account.

```
/**
 * @param {ObjectExpression} objectAst
 */
function getPropertiesList(objectAst) {
    let propertiesList = objectAst.value.properties
    if (!propertiesList.every(p => p.type == "Property"))
        throw new Error("Properties field has elements that aren't of type `Property`")
    return propertiesList
}
```

Can anyone give some insight on how the typescript handles one case differently from the other?

Typescript can use checks to make a certain type more specific (as the first example works), but apparently it can't perform those checks on arrays.

Can this be considered a bug in the typescript compiler (as both pieces of code should obviously return the same type)?

EDIT: to give some context and testability, I imported the types from `recast` as follows:

```
/**
 * @typedef { import('recast').types.namedTypes.ObjectExpression} ObjectExpression 
 * @typedef { import('recast').types.namedTypes.Property} Property 
*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the compiler doesn't understand that `array.every()` can be used as a [type guard](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) on the type of `array`.  Furthermore, the callback function `p => p.type == "Property"` is also not inferred to be a type guard on the type of `p`.  The compiler is pretty good about analyzing inline code for potential type narrowing, but it pretty much [gives up (see microsoft/TypeScript#9998)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) when control flow passes into functions.

If you want TypeScript to understand that calling `boolean`-returning functions acts as a type guard, you need to manually annotate such functions as a [user-defined type guard](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).  A function like `foo(x: T): boolean` can be changed to `foo(x: T): x is U` where "`x is U"` is a *type predicate*.  If `foo(val)` returns `true`, then the compiler will narrow `val` to `U`.  Otherwise it won't.

For the callback, this requires changing `p => p.type == "Property"` to `(p): p is Property => type == "Property"`. For `array.every()`, well, that method is [declared in the standard library](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.7.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1140) inside the `Array<T>` interface.  Luckily, you are allowed to [merge in extra method overloads to interfaces](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) (beware that if your code is in a module you may have to specifically use [global augmentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) to add to global interfaces like `Array<T>`).  It would look like this:

```
interface Array<T> {
    every<U extends T>(cb: (x: T) => x is U): this is Array<U>;
}
```

Now the compiler will see that if the callback is a type-guard function, then `every()` itself acts as a type guard.  And your code will work as desired:

```
function getPropertiesList(objectAst: ObjectAST): Property[] {
    let propertiesList = objectAst.value.properties
    if (!propertiesList.every((p): p is Property => p.type == "Property"))
        throw new Error("Properties field has elements that aren't of type `Property`")
    return propertiesList
}
```

This is likely too much work for a single use of `every()`, though.  In practice, you should probably just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) and move on.  Type assertions are meant for situations where you know more about the types than the compiler does; this is a reasonable time to use one:

```
function getPropertiesListAssert(objectAst: ObjectAST): Property[] {
    let propertiesList = objectAst.value.properties
    if (!propertiesList.every(p => p.type == "Property"))
        throw new Error("Properties field has elements that aren't of type `Property`")
    return propertiesList as Property[]; // assert
}
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEFkEMBMFNQK4AdQBcCeTYGcCwAoASwDtVYAnAM0gGN4AFcgey3I1AG81NYAuUAESMWFDANABfAiTJVa8AMpMAtrFQALEgHMAogBts8Lhiz8BS1Ru37D4qfhPwA8gCMAVrBqoAggoAqoAC8nKAEoOGgAG6Qegh8nGERSUjMrKiEOPze5OSQ6AA8wmnooAA+oBZqmsS6BrAAfInh9vbSpBTUdKDZuQV+9Qn4SbCRFAUAqqCwAB5kxNDYoP0AFDQu-MvT-H4AlEED06CEi+M7-FaLx905efnj9QDcBK34lAjEXoRMxKBaakWiDLYAAyx1QyyY7k8PmwqH4rg8Xl8u34ALY6AA2gBdQZJPRqUApERsIGg2FBUCQxEw1AAOmisVgtKJaSBTSOlFAywAhCzATgyXSRmNlsskGdCUdFmj2IEBkhaY4gsEhKlROgBDsduykhpmAB3UDEWCGnQ5JjkZaq4npHCgSgZPTQUDqSCLWD41SkRYaSCoUCQciwYgAcn9TE5SoABjL0FHNeyg6gEOQfnySQKwc8CDnXu9Pt9fv81RmQWDvNhDGwIVCkbD4bWfP4JbHsbiIvj-enbWXycEqdCK3SGXFmSWe+zCJyed3SWDacLyOgxftCYqeMrBLHNdqhkkInqmIbjabzZbray7Q6Pc7Xe7PcHUD7Xf7A8Gw5TIxuY+O4wm9+ESYpmm45zuSbqgK2WIPKAIABpWojPEAA)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. It gave me a lot more insight, and more stuff to read.